# Where to store database credentials in Electron app

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sqlite, electron

I just started on a new Electron project that needs to access a database, e.g. SQLite. The database will be on a shared drive that should be accessed by the Electron app.

To do that, I need to provide the path as well as the password for the database to the Electron app. Since it's desktop application, I deliver the whole application incl. the database credentials to the user.

From my point of view, this is not a good approach from a security perpective.

**So the question is, where do I store these details, especially the credentials?**

The same issue applies if I use e.g. another database like MySQL. There, I also need to store the host and the credentials.

Comment: Generally, desktop applications (or any client side apps for that matter) don't have direct access to a shared database. There is an additional layer (accessed via an API) between them that the app connects to, that makes the actual calls to the database.

Comment: @Ivar - I understand, that already makes it a bit clearer to me. But this only shifts the problem from one application to another, doesn't it? Then where should the API store the database credentials? Would be great if you could clarify that, thank you.

Comment: This API is running on a server (just like your database would) where others cannot access the credentials. This server (or the application running on this server) only listens to specific endpoints and returns what your program decides to return. So the credentials live on that server. How specifically depends on a lot of things. But they could for example be in the environment variables where the application gets them from.

Comment: @Ivar - I understand, but is it really required to send a web service request to your API via the internet, even if the database to be accessed is in the same location as your frontend application?